# My angular service is not making http request. I have spent more time on this then whole project

Tags: angular, typescript

client.service.ts

```
  create(client: Client): Observable<Client[] | null> {
    console.log("Starting debugging")
    return this.clients$.pipe(
      take(1),
      switchMap((clients) =>
        console.log("Inside switchmap")
        this._httpClient
          .post<Client>(this.baseUrl + 'create/', client, this.httpOptions)
          .pipe(
            map((newClient) => {
              const result = [{ ...newClient, ...clients }];
              this._clients.next(result);
              return result;
            })
          )
      )
    );
  }
```

client.component.ts

```
  add() {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(CreateClientComponent, {
      data: {},
      width: '40%',
      disableClose: true
    });

    dialogRef
      .afterClosed()
      .pipe(
        filter(Boolean),
        tap((client) => this._clientService.create(client)),
        takeUntil(this._destroy)
      )
      .subscribe();
  }
```

I am not getting any log from switchmap. Though when i am submitting my client, I am getting new client in console. But there is no http request to backend, neither there is any request log in chome. Please note that I have tried with already populated clients but for no use.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you try adding a take() to the inner http post? It's been a while since I've used rxjs but I think it's because the http.post is not subscribed to

Comment: Wow. That do work. Just one more secondary question. Is there more elegant way rather than multiple subscribe. I just want to show my updated clients after creating one.

Comment: Just change your `tap()` to a `switchMap()` and you won't have to use nested subscribe. Also you seem to be missing a return on `this._httpClient.post` in the service for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Your create method is returning the following: Observable<Client[] | null>. An any observable is effectively just a paperweight in memory until you subscribe to it, exactly what @Phix said in the comment. Add .subscribe to your method call.

```js
dialogRef
      .afterClosed()
      .pipe(
        filter(Boolean),
        tap((client) => this._clientService.create(client)***.subscribe()***),
        takeUntil(this._destroy)
      )
      .subscribe();
```